# How to check if closed captioning is selected on Android accessibility settings

Tags: android

Is it possible to check if closed captioning is enabled by the user in Settings --> Accessibility section of Android phone? 
I want to check if Closed captioning is enabled/disabled in Accessibility.

Answer (score 2):

Yes It's possible (since api level 19).

You can check captioning state with [isEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/CaptioningManager.html#isEnabled()) method of [CaptioningManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/CaptioningManager.html).

```
CaptioningManager captioningManager =
                    (CaptioningManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAPTIONING_SERVICE);

if(captioningManager.isEnabled()){
    //do your stuff
}
```